# Dados em formato JSON não são mostrados

Tags: php, json, pdo

Olá, tenho o seguinte código php:

```
<?php

require("config_local.php"); //conexao com o banco de dados

$area = "eua";
$st = "ny";


$sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT prop,old_no,emissao,area,country,e_name FROM table1 WHERE area = :area AND st= :st ");
$sql->bindValue(":area",$area,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindValue(":st",$st,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->execute();

$result = $sql->fetchAll();
$n = $sql->rowCount();


echo $n ; // mostra o numero correto
echo json_encode($result); // nao mostra nada, tela em branco
```

O problema é que, quando tento executar essa consulta, me retorna a tela em branco, porém se tiro um dos campos a serem mostrados, recebo os dados corretamente.

A pergunta é, existe algum tipo de limitação do PHP quanto a mostrar uma grande quantidades de dados/campos em formato JSON? Se sim, como poderia dribá-la? Pois preciso mostrar esses e mais alguns campos...

Obrigado.

Comment: Não parece ter nada errado no seu código, tente validat o retorno da função "json_encode" se ao invés de uma string, retornar o boolean false, chame json_last_error pra saber qual o problema. documentação da função: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-last-error.php

Comment: Não, o código funciona normalmente, o problema é que parece que o php "limita" a quantidade de informações a serem mostradas. Fui testando a consulta adicionando um campo de cada vez, que chega em um ponto que quando adiciona mais 1 campo, deixa de exibir.

Comment: Usei o jsonlasterror, peguei a exceção JSON_ERROR_UTF8, se conseguir algo posto aqui...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opa, era erro de codificação utf8.

Resolvi colocando na minha classe de conexão a linha:

```
$pdo->query("SET NAMES utf8;");
```

Ficando assim:

```
<?php
try{
 $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb","root","");
 $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 $pdo->query("SET NAMES utf8;");
 $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

}catch(PDOException $e){

 echo 'Falha ao conectar - ERROR:' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Obrigado!